# Linq Min() of Non-zero values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with columns `OneStopPrice; MultiStopPrice; NonStopPrice`. I want to have `Min()` for all 3 columns. But if `Min()` of any column is 0, It must be ignored.

```
OneStop | NonStop | MultiStop
-----------------------------
233.23  | 0.0     | 355.23
```

Here NonStop must be then considered as highest value so as to ignore it.

Anyone have idea for this using `LinQ`?

I have used query as follows:

```
var data = odyResults.GroupBy(logEle => new { logEle.Air.FromCity, logEle.Air.ToCity }, (key, group) => new{
       FromCity = key.FromCity,
       ToCity = key.ToCity,
       OneStopPrice = group.Min(x=>x.Air.OneStopPrice),
       MultiStopPrice = group.Min(x => x.Air.MultiStopPrice),
       NonStopPrice = group.Min(x => x.Air.NonStopPrice),
       FromToCityCount = group.Count()
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean by *ignored*? Property should not present in anonymous object?

Comment: `group.Where(c => c.OneStopPrice != 0).Min(c => c.OneStopPrice)` ? Not sure, what you are trying to do, though.

Comment: Ignored means i want value next to lowest. Means Min() of NonZero values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter out the zeros:

```
NonStopPrice = group.Where(x => x.Air.NonStopPrice > 0)
                    .Min(x => x.Air.NonStopPrice),
```

Comment: That's because `group.Where(x => x.Air.NonStopPrice > 0)` is empty, you should treat this case accordingly.

Comment: You can try this: `group.Select(x => x.Air.NonStopPrice).Where(p => p > 0).DefaultIfEmpty().Min()`

Comment: But then I have output as 1234.5, 452.12,0.0 for Paris - Lon Which i dont want to have in my output

Comment: @PoojaKhatri So what do you want to have? `-1`? `null`?